# R: ggplot:: geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a line graph in ggplot and I am having difficulty diagnosing my error. I've read through nearly all the similar threads, but have been unable to solve my issue.

I am trying to plot Japanese CPI. I downloaded the data online from FRED.

my str looks like:

```
str(jpycpi)

data.frame: 179 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DATE           : Factor w/ 179 levels "2000-04-01","2000-05-01",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ JPNCPIALLMINMEI: num  103 103 103 102 103 ...
```

My code to plot:

```
ggplot(jpycpi, aes(x=jpycpi$DATE, y=jpycpi$JPNCPIALLMINMEI)) + geom_line()
```

it gives me an error saying:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

I have tried the following and have been able to plot it, but the graph x bar is distorted for some odd reason. That code is below:

```
ggplot(jpycpi, aes(x=jpycpi$DATE, y=jpycpi$JPNCPIALLMINMEI, group=1)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Does `jpycpi$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(jpycpi$DATE))` fix it?  If so, I can explain.

Comment: it did, thank you. An explanation owuld be great. I understand why we would need to convert it to a date, but if its a factor why wouldn't we do:               jpycpi$DATE <- as.Date(as.factor(jpycpi$DATE))?      In other words, why as.character?

Comment: `as.Date(as.factor(thing which is a factor))` is the same as `as.Date(thing which is a factor)`.  I explain why an intermediate `as.character` may be necessary in the answer I just wrote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "Each group consists of only one observation" error message happens because your **x** aesthetic is a factor.  ggplot takes that to mean that your independent variable is categorical, which doesn't make sense in conjunction with `geom_line`.

In this case, the right way to fix it is to convert that column of the data to a [`Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) vector.  ggplot understands how to use all of R's date/time classes as the **x** aesthetic.

Converting from a factor to a Date is a little tricky.  A direct conversion,

```
jpycpi$DATE <- as.Date(jpycpi$DATE)
```

works in R version 3.3.1, but, if I remember correctly, would give nonsense results in older versions of the interpreter, because `as.Date` would look only at the *ordinals* of the factor levels, not at their labels.  Instead, one should write

```
jpycpi$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(jpycpi$DATE))
```

Conversion from a factor to a character vector *does* look at the labels, so the subsequent conversion to a Date object will do the Right Thing.

You probably got a factor for $DATE in the first place because you used `read.table` or `read.csv` to load up the data set.  The default behavior of these functions is to attempt to convert each column to a numeric vector, and failing that, to convert it to a factor.  (See ?[`type.convert`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html) for the exact behavior.)  If you're going to be importing lots of data with date columns, it's worth learning how to use the `colClasses` argument to `read.table`; this is more efficient and doesn't have gotchas like the above.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation, it was very helpful and I will look into type.convert when I get home.